# Sending HTTP request with Java Play (WSClient initialization)

Tags: java, sockets, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following piece of code taken from the official Play 2.6 docs that define a client class,

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.libs.ws.*;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class MyClient implements WSBodyReadables, WSBodyWritables {
    private WSClient ws;

    @Inject
    public MyClient(WSClient ws) {
        this.ws = ws;
        sendRequest();
    }

    public void sendRequest() {
        WSRequest request = ws.url("http://example.com");

        WSRequest complexRequest = request.addHeader("headerKey", "headerValue")
                .setRequestTimeout(Duration.of(1000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
                .addQueryParameter("paramKey", "paramValue");

        CompletionStage<? extends WSResponse> responsePromise = complexRequest.get();
    }
}
```

Now I have a socket actor that handles incoming socket messages. I want to fire an HTTP request every time a new message comes through the socket.

My problem is I don't know how to initialize MyClient class to use its sendRequest method.

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if (message instanceof String) {
        out.tell("I received your message: " + message, self());
        MyClient a = new MyClient(); //problem here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must inject it, the same way you did in `MyClass`:

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedAbstractActor {

    private MyClient client;

    @Inject
    public MyActor(MyClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        client.sendRequest();
    }
}
```

If there is some problem that dont let you use this (ex you dont control how the actor is created), add more info to your question.

Comment: Previously, I instantiated MyActor like so: `return WebSocket.Text.accept(request ->
                ActorFlow.actorRef(MyActor::props,
                        actorSystem, materializer
                )
        );`
That no longer works, so how can I do it?

Comment: Then I think you can inject the`MyClient` object when you create the actor, and then instead of using `MyActor::props`, use `Props.create(MyActor.class, THE_INJECTED_INSTANCE_OF_MYCLIENT)`.